# Canvas.scale() on Android. Redraw full screen

Tags: android, canvas, scale

So I'm using the example on Android Developers to implement pinch to zoom on my Activity.

Im Scaling A Custom View which has a ScrollView(and other things) inside it.

When im scaling, only the actual displayed Screen gets resized - but i want the scaled down things to show more of their content, because they have more space to do so when scaled down.
I want them to use all the full screen space.

My Custom Views ondraw method just looks like this:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

this is what it looks like right now

[image]

If anything is unclear, just leave a comment. Any Help is appreciated
edit: i made my custom View another Background color and now i see that my View is still full screen just not the childs.

Comment: No, I scrapped the zoom feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the size of the view that is being scaled with a `LayoutParams`.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001707/view-not-showing-all-content-after-scaling-down/17010535#17010535) has more detail on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am Assuming you are having other layouts apart from your ScrollView which are in Horizontal Orientation or Vertical. Try using weight option in the XML Attributes of ScrollView with a value of 1.0, it might solve your problem.

Comment: My view is extending Relative Layout. so i can't set any weights