# View not showing all content after scaling down

Tags: android, canvas, view, zooming, scale

After using the `View.setScaleX()` and `View.setScaleY()` methods to make my `view` smaller, the result only shows the content that was already displayed, leaving out the rest that didn't fit on the screen when it was zoomed in. How can I force it to show the rest of the content?

XML: activity_main.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

JAVA: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zoom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        int textViewSize = 100;
        int tableColCount = 15;
        int tableRowCount = 15;

        for (int row = 0; row < tableRowCount; row++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for (int col = 0; col < tableColCount; col++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText("" + row + "." + col);
                textView.setTextSize(20.0f);
                tr.addView(textView, textViewSize, textViewSize);
            } // for
            table.addView(tr);
        } // for
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_zoom_in:
                table.setScaleX(1.0f);
                table.setScaleY(1.0f);
                break;
            case R.id.action_zoom_out:
                table.setScaleX(0.25f);
                table.setScaleY(0.25f);
                break;
        } // switch
        return true;
    }
}
```

SCREEN SHOTS: [Zoomed In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA9sy.png) | [Zoomed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bikg9.png)

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722300/canvas-scale-on-android-redraw-full-screen) was very much the same as mine, but there was no code nor answer.

Comment: canvas? what canvas? i dont see any canvas...

Comment: Sorry, I mean `View.setScaleX()` and `View.setScaleY()`, where the view is `table`. I updated it.

Comment: isnt setScale[X¦Y] used only for animations?

Comment: I don't know anything about animations in android. So I'm not sure. However, the methods do exist for `View`, as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out setting the size of the `view` manually (instead of using `wrap_content`) did the trick. This is all it really took:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams tableLP = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    textViewSize * tableColCount, textViewSize * tableRowCount);
table.setLayoutParams(tableLP);
```

I also set the pivot point to 0 to keep the view in the top left corner.

```
table.setPivotX(0);
table.setPivotY(0);
```

In regards to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) (who commented on my original question) I looked into animations and discovered that using a `ViewPropertyAnimator` did a pretty nice job as well. To use this class you just call `View.animate()`.

After setting the size of the `view` that will be scaled, and the pivot point of that `view`, you can either use the basic scaling method with no animation,

```
// zoom in by 50%
float scale = 0.5f;
view.setScaleX(table.getScaleX() + scale);
view.setScaleY(table.getScaleY() + scale);
```

or the scaling method with animation.

```
// zoom in by 50%
float scale = 0.5f;
table.animate().scaleXBy(scale).scaleYBy(scale).setDuration(0).start();
```

Here is a full example of the program in the original question:

```
package com.example.zoom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        int textViewSize = 100;
        int tableColCount = 15;
        int tableRowCount = 15;

        for (int row = 0; row < tableRowCount; row++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for (int col = 0; col < tableColCount; col++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(row + "." + col);
                textView.setTextSize(20.0f);
                tr.addView(textView, textViewSize, textViewSize);
            } // for
            table.addView(tr);
        } // for

        // manually set the size to make sure the entire view is drawn and will be seen when scaled down
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams tableLP = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(textViewSize * tableColCount, textViewSize * tableRowCount);
        table.setLayoutParams(tableLP);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
        // set default scale to 0 in case no scale occurs
        float scale = 0.0f;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_zoom_in:
                scale = 0.5f;
                break;
            case R.id.action_zoom_out:
                // use negative to decrease the scale
                scale = -0.5f;
                break;
        } // switch

        // set pivot to 0 to keep view in the top left corner
        table.setPivotX(0);
        table.setPivotY(0);
        // add new scale with current scale to get View.scaleBy() equivalent
        table.setScaleX(table.getScaleX() + scale);
        table.setScaleY(table.getScaleY() + scale);
//      could use an animation instead
//      table.animate().scaleXBy(scale).scaleYBy(scale).setDuration(0).start();
        return true;
    }
}
```